# Fetching tab title in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have implemented ViewPageIndicator and it is running fine. I have 3 tabs with names "Tab1", "Tab2", and "Tab3". What I want is the tab name when I scroll the tab.

Could anyone let me know how to fetch the tab title of the current tab that is being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title for the current page from your `PagerAdapter`:

```
int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
CharSequence pageTitle = pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(currentPage);
```

Comment: Hi, I used it in main activity which extends SherlockFragmentActivity that sets the PagerAdapter. I am getting the tab name of first tab. When i swipe, i need to get the name of 2nd tab and so on. Could you please suggest?